# Error occurred when using tocloft package in LaTeX file

Tags: xetex, tocloft, documentclass-writing

I want to write a document class myself, which uses the tocloft package to edit the TOC format.

An error occurs when compiling a TeX file using this document class:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \ttl@finishall
                  
?
```

When I removed all the stuffs using tocloft in the document class, the error still exists.

When I use tocloft in an TeX file, I still get an error, regardless of standard document classes or custom document classes, and I get an error without adding anything about tocloft.

Is this what is the reason? How to solve?

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile because I need to process Chinese text.

Comment: would you like to upload a minimal code that reproduces the error

Comment: the full log would have shown which file that is in have you deleted .aux .toc etc generated files since changing the package loading?

Comment: there isn't a mwe, because i just use the standard document class and the tocloft package and there isn't anything in the document environment

Comment: wow! when i deleted ALL auxiliary files, the error disappeared. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log (which you did not show) would have made it clear the error was in the aux file

Packages often write package-defined commands to the aux file, and so if you edit the main document removing a package, you may find the `aux` file contains commands that are no longer understood.  You can simply delete the aux (and other generated files for tables of contents or index) and let LaTeX write new ones.